# Having trouble making a Discord bot that can screenshot a webpage and then post that screenshot in a channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is very hard to explain through just the title, so I will summarize a bit more here. I am trying to make my Discord bot screenshot a specific webpage, and then post the screenshot of the webpage into a channel. The catch is, I want the bot to take extra words in a command that a user writes, such as "!stats USERNAME" and include those extra words into the link it will be screenshotting. Here is a screenshot to help better understand what I am trying to say.

(USERNAME is the extra text that the user will be typing in after the command.)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEqwj.png

After it goes to said webpage, it would take a screenshot of the webpage and post it onto the Discord channel that the command was typed in.
I am writing in JavaScript.

Any help would be AMAZING. I have looked everywhere and have not found a solution, as I do not know how to look up my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set up arguments, then take the 2nd element of the args array.

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === 'stats') {
   const link = `https://sky.lea.moe/stats/${args[1]}`;
   // Your code using link
}
```

Learn about arguments [Here](http://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html)